# How different are my two code bases?

Tags: diff

I have two sets of source code that should be very similar. I need to find where they are different and address that.

These files are not in any SCM. Is there some way to get a report like this:

```
dir/file1 -- exists only in version A
dir/file2 -- exists only in version B
dir/file3 -- B includes 5 additions, 2 deletions
dir2 -- exists only in version A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff -ru -x '.DS_Store' dirA dirB | diffstat
```

Answer (score 0):

Any decent diff tool (e.g. WinMerge, DiffMerge, etc.) will be able to report on the differences between two folder structures.

Just put version A in a folder called `VersionA`, and version B in a folder called `Version B` and run the diff tool on them.

To generate a report in WinMerge select "Tools" -> "Generate Report".

Answer (score 0):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org) can open two folders and then gives you an overview over missing/added/different files.

Comment: Will it be possible to get a report output. I need to be able to share the results

Answer (score 0):

I have used this tool and it is very handy for us to use.

It has additional PMD scanning too

Check this out.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/diffreport/